Old horror movie about haunted village/town?
I watched this great horror movie in 1995-2000 (from a Z studio I guess). I remembered a few scenes and bit of story:

A group of boys and girls finds a village when they are on tour and decide to rest in the village on request of the mayor.
The mayor's family provides housing for the group.
The mayor's family consists of his spouse, two young beautiful girls, and I guess one son.
The next day, they found one group member is missing. They search for days to find them, and found something is not right about the village. 
That day, other members go missing and are killed.
One of boys was killed by the mayor's daughter. It's night. The boy was trying to sleep and he heard the girl calling to him. He replied through the window because he was naked and the girl asked him if he needs anything. He says "no," and then turns back, but at the same time the door opens, and the girl comes in. After they have sex, the girl kills the boy by putting her tongue in the boy's heart and taking it out.
Another boy goes with two other village girls (in traditional European frocks) to the forest to help them to find cherries. They stop to take a rest. The boy sits on one stone and girls are on the ground, and they engage in foreplay with each other and so on.
Two or three of the remaining people find their missing friend dead in a tree house with his head on the table... they get scared and decide to get out of the village/town.
One boy realizes that he saw a telephone in the mayor's house; he decides to call someone for help. He goes to the mayor's house, where he finds the mayor's daughter. She takes off her top, approaches the boy, and gives him a blowjob. In the middle of it, her teeth turn out to be monster-like sharp and long and she kills boy by biting him during the blow job.
The last scene I remembered is that the last two persons successfully escape the village by bike, but before they go far on the road they die when a wire fence cuts off their heads. A male farmer picks their heads up from the road and walks towards the village.

In the end the mayor and his family members are standing in a graveyard; the mayor says something and after that there's fog and the whole graveyard disappears.

Horror film 2001 Maniacs with Robert Englund from 2005:

While traveling on vacation to Florida, the college friends Anderson Lee, Cory Jones and Nelson Elliot meet the gorgeous Joey and Kat in a gas station traveling with their gay friend Ricky to the same location. Anderson gives his phone number to Joey in Florida. The teenagers decide to take a shortcut and they find a detour through an old road leading to the Southern town of Pleasant Valley. They are welcomed by the local Mayor Buckman as guests of honor together with Joey, Kat, Ricky and the Afro-American biker Malcolm and his Chinese girlfriend Leah and invited to stay for their Guts and Glory Jubilee with free lodging, meals and booze at Granny Boone's hotel, and dancing, games and a mouth-watering barbecue in the climax of the jubilee. The group accepts the invitation but sooner they find who will supply the meat for the feast.

Everything you've described is in there (including that oral castration scene with those giant teeth). They're killed one by one, two survive and in the end:

As the two students drive away on their motorcycle, they are decapitated by barbed wire. The heads are picked up by Hucklebilly who walks down the road and fades away.

You can see the trailer here [WARNING: GORE & NUDITY].

